# Is it bad practice to run an UPDATE script in Project Server

Tags: sql-server, project-server

I am using the Project Server application which sits on top of a database. I have hundreds of edits to make to Project Server but It’s unrealistic to edit all of the Projects, one at a time. Instead of doing it one at a time, I was thinking of running an UPDATE sql script to write directly to the database.

Is this considered bad practice and would it break project server?

Comment: Yes to both if you modify the undocumented databases. For the reporting database it's bad practice but maybe, just maybe, it won't break the it. BTW you didn't explain which database and which tables were modified, or even what you're trying to do

Comment: Project Server has its own SOAP and REST API and methods of importing data into projects. There's no reason to modify projects by hand or wrse, start modifying its internal databases

Comment: Check the [Project Server Programmability Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/project-server-2013-architecture-and-programmability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you do any writing on the DB by yourself or touch the schema you just lost your support from microsoft. They reserve the right to do any change in the db with each update.

Do not do it. Don't.

Use PSI or the REST API. Those are your friends.